# Joining Multiple table in C# Model

Tags: c#

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public class UserInfo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Department Departments { get; set; }
    public Department Designations { get; set; }
    public string ReportingPerson { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public class Department
{
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentDescription { get; set; }
}
```

}

When binding data to UserInfo from the database, Department Name getting Null.

```
   namespace WindowsFormsApp1
   {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string conn = "Data Source =*; Initial Catalog = *; User Id = *; Password =*;";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        IEnumerable<UserInfo> returnValues = connection.Query<UserInfo>(@"Select FirstName,LastName,FullName,DepartmentCode,DepartmentName,DesignationCode,DesignationName from System.UserInformation");
        connection.Close();
        label1.Text = returnValues.Single().Departments.DepartmentName;
    }
}
```

}

SQL Query :

```
Select FirstName,LastName,FullName,DepartmentCode,DepartmentName,DesignationCode,DesignationName from System.UserInformation
```

SQL Result:
FirstName   LastName    FullName    DepartmentCode  DepartmentName  DesignationCode DesignationName
Chandra Shakar  Chandra Shakar  DPT000001   IT  DEG000001   Jr. Programmer

Department Name getting null. Can you Please help me?

Comment: How could we possibly help you if we have no idea what `UserManager.GlobalInfo.Get(userName);` is. You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: I am calling the Data access class. Please check the data access class :
public IEnumerable<UserInfo> GetBy(string KeyFieldCode)
        {
            IEnumerable<UserInfo> returnValues = connection.Query<UserInfo>(@"Select * from System.UserInformation where UserName = @UserName", new { @UserName = KeyFieldCode });
            connection.Close();
            return returnValues;
        }

Comment: What data access class? I don't see any. Please **read** how to post a [mcve] (it's a link!) and [edit] your quesiton

Comment: Getting all user information details using this class.
public IEnumerable<UserInfo> GetBy(string KeyFieldCode)
        {
            IEnumerable<UserInfo> returnValues = connection.Query<UserInfo>(@"Select * from System.UserInformation where UserName = @UserName", new { @UserName = KeyFieldCode });
            connection.Close();
            return returnValues;
        }

Comment: To add additional information, please edit your question instead of commenting.

Comment: I have already edit the question.

Comment: @ChandraShakar you are new here that's why you are facing problem. Since you are using query to fetch the data. you need to costruct the ur `UserInfo` class using `join`. How do you think `"Select * from System.UserInformation where UserName = @UserName"` this query will fetch `department` data which is in another table.

Comment: yes, @Sumitraj ... it's my fault. FYI: it's was a view. Now I have already added the query.

Comment: Have you checked running `view` on your `ssms` whether it is fetching result or not.

Comment: Or just post your method and complete `UserInfo` class. Exact one don't edit.

Comment: @Sumitraj, Yes i have checked it's getting data
Result : 
FirstName LastName FullName DepartmentCode DepartmentName DesignationCode DesignationName
Chandra Shakar Chandra Shakar DPT000001 IT DEG000001 System Analyst

Comment: Post your method and class buddy. No one here can speculate everything with less information.

Comment: @Sumitraj Full Class, Method Add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `UserInfo` class

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string DesignationCode { get; set; }
    public string DesignationName { get; set; }
}
```

and this.

```
label1.Text = returnValues.Single().DepartmentName;
```

Although i cn't imagine what would you achieve with this result.

Comment: yes, you are right, but what about multiple table joining.
example: I have a view with 100 columns and join with 3 tables (Programmatically 3 tables contains 3 Model). I can't add 3 models together. is there any other options ?

Comment: Google `Entity Framework` and learn it. . It will solve all your issues

Comment: Thanks, for your advice. I have already found where was the issue. and my problem has been resolved.
Again Thanks, buddy.